# Loopback- model name automatically created can't change it simple and user-friendly

Tags: mysql, models, strongloop, loopback

While creating model using loopback , it can be created only using the mysql table name. If it changed to some other names,it throws an error of "table doesn't exists"., how it can be rectified?

Comment: How you change that?

Answer (score 0):

Loopback models are basically mapping of your Mysql tables. So when you use datasource.discoverAndBuildModels loopback will create Models with the same table name and methods like GET, Post, PUT, DELETE etc with each models. So if you want to change model name to more user friendly... make your table name more user friendly!